# Column index order SQLite creates table

Tags: android, sqlite

This is the query that I use to create a table

```
create table site_table(
   _id integer primary key autoincrement,
   name_site text,
   url text,
   login text,
   pass text
);
```

I called `Cursor.getColumnNames()` and noticed that columns order are `id, login, pass, name, url`.

So, if I want a value I have to get it by the index `Cursor.getString(index)`. Until I debugged I was messing up calling the wrong index, but now I wonder, why SQLite saves that way? Why it does not follow that way I created `id, name_site, url, login and pass`?


Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, if I want a value I have to get it by the index
>   Cursor.getString(index)

So for example for this reason you should always use

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ColName")); // or better getColumnIndex(CONSTANT)
```

This method saves all of us and ensure that you never get wrong results. Generally this method is recommended and also storing `COLUMN_NAMES` as `CONSTANTS` in separated class is very, very useful and efficient practise.

**Note:** Order depends on projection i.e. `select name, lastname from table`

Comment: Thanks that answer solved for me, in response to NOTE, that is not the case, I guess, 'cause when the query method, I didn't specify the column orders. Method: database.query(TABLE_NAME, WHERE ID, ..rest is null);

Comment: @Rigotti you are welcome :) i only mentioned that it also depends on projection if you are using raw statements.

Answer (score 1):

That data is ordered by the order your requested it in your query, not the order you created the table with.  So you probably changed the order in your query that generated said cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Columns order in your cursor depends on projection. To be sure you use correct column index use `c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("COLUMN_NAME"))` where `c` is your cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I just made the experience first hand:

The indices of the columns of the cursor as a result of a

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ...

query have sometimes (not always) a different order that what SQLITE Database Browser shows as column order in the Database Structure tab. So referencing the columns via getColumnIndex seems to be the only safe way.